# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 59

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps

**What i am doing:**
I am trying to make a reverse geocoding in android

**I am getting error as::**
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 59: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Agram, Bengaluru, Karnataka, India&sensor=false

NOte: that request gets a json response in browser but not from my class below

***This line is giving this error::***

```
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
```

---

**JSONfunctions.java**

```
public class JSONfunctions {

    public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url) {
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        JSONObject jArray = null;

        // Download JSON data from URL
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        // Convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try {

            jArray = new JSONObject(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return jArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider URL encoding your URL parameter values.

Comment: @laalto ... Can you please show as an answer, i am new to make encoding requests !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java URL encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`URLEncoder.encode()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to encode the value of your `address` parameter `"Agram, Bengaluru, Karnataka, India"` before putting it in the URL string so that it becomes something like

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Agram,+Bengaluru,+Karnataka,+India&sensor=false
```

i.e. spaces changed to `+` and other special octets represented as `%xx`.

Browsers do smart URL encoding for strings entered in the address bar automatically so that's why it works there.

Comment: When i try that in the respone i am getting as `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null,`

Comment: Don't encode the entire URL, just the value of the parameter that is part of the URL.

Comment: laalto that was helpful, thnx.

Answer (score 6):

Build your url like,

```
final StringBuilder request = new StringBuilder(
        "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false");
request.append("&language=").append(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
request.append("&address=").append(
        URLEncoder.encode(locationName, "UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am using httpclient 4.3.3

```
String messagestr = "Welcome to Moqui World";
String url="http://my.example.com/api/sendhttp.phpauthkey="+URLEncoder.encode("17djssnvndkfjb110d3","UTF-8")+"&mobiles=91"+URLEncoder.encode(contactNumber,"UTF-8")+"&message="+URLEncoder.encode(messagestr,"UTF8")+"&sender="+URLEncoder.encode("WMOQUI","UTF-8")+"&route=4";

HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

It's working fine for me. I hope this may help you.