# Issue in making http call in android due to String format - illegal character in query at index 81

Tags: java, android, httprequest, stringescapeutils

In my application, I have to get the data from JSON service based on TYPE and SUB TYPE selected by user and show the data to user.

I know how to make an http request, how to parse the response, but the URL is creating an issue.

The URL is like this:

```
http://abc.abc.ab.abc/myappnameapiii/index.php/Api/getAllInfoctoryUser_type?data={"type":"TYP","sub_type":"SUB"}
```

I tried escaping the `"` with  `StringEscapeUtils`. But that didn't help.

Sample code:

```
String baseUrl = "http://abc.abc.ab.abc/myappnameapiii/index.php/Api/getAllInfoctoryUser_type?data={";
String typeInfo = "\"type\":\""+selectedType+"\",\"sub_type\":\""+selectedSubType+"\"}";
typeInfo = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(typeInfo);
String finalUrl = baseUrl + typeInfo;

//Call asynctask using finalUrl
....
....
```

I am getting this exception when I make an http request:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 81: http://abc.abc.ab.abc/myappnameapiii/index.php/Api/getAllInfoctoryUser_type?data={\"type\":\"TYP\",\"sub_type\":\"SUB\"}
```

Here is what I tried for resolving this:

**First:**

I tried unescaping the `typeInfo` just before I make a call in my AsyncTask like this:

```
try {
        String finalUrl = baseUrl.concat(typeInfo);*/
        String finalUrl = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(url[0]);
        object = RestJsonClient.connect(finalUrl);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This doesn't help. It throws exception as:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 81: http://abc.abc.ab.abc/myappnameapiii/index.php/Api/getAllInfoctoryUser_type?data={"type":"TYP","sub_type":"SUB"}
```

**Second:**

Referring [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27126839/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-illegal-character-in-query-at-index-59) I tried using UTF-8 encoding according to answer on that post.

Code snippet:

```
String baseUrl = url[0];
String typeInfo =  URLEncoder.encode(url[1], "UTF-8");

String finalUrl = baseUrl.concat(typeInfo);
//String finalUrl = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(url[0]);
object = RestJsonClient.connect(finalUrl);
```

Here, I passed the URL to asynctask in two Strings instead of one finalUrl string.

This also throws exception such as:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 81: http://abc.abc.ab.abc/myappnameapiii/index.php/Api/getAllInfoctoryUser_type?data={%5C%22type%5C%22%3A%5C%22MANUFACTURER%5C%22%2C%5C%22sub_type%5C%22%3A%5C%22GOLD%5C%22%7D
```

I am clueless regarding what to do now. It would be great if someone can help.

P.S: The same url shows the result in browser. The url is correct and data is there on server.

***EDIT***

According to @Tejas's comment, I tried passing the data in a POST request's body like this:

```
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "TYP"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sub_type", "SUB"));
    //request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

    object = RestJsonClient.post( baseUrl, params);
```

Code of `RestJsonClient.post` method is working fine in my other calls. So I am not posting all of the code here. The snippet from that method after I get the response is:

```
    HttpEntity httpentity = response.getEntity();

    if (httpentity != null) {
        InputStream instream = httpentity.getContent();
        String result = convertStreamToString(instream);
        System.out.println("result: " + result);
        json = new JSONObject(result);
        instream.close();
    }
```

Now there is no error. I get response from the service with status code OK (200). But no data in result.

```
08-10 10:33:42.141 7003-9831/jbc.gss.com.jewelnet I/System.out: response in restjson claas- org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@27ee4f83
08-10 10:33:42.141 7003-9831/pkg.name V/response code: 200
08-10 10:33:42.142 7003-9831/pkg.name I/System.out: result: {"response":"failure","message":" Not data available"}
08-10 10:33:42.150 7003-7003/pkg.name W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for data
```

Its not possible for me to request the change in service if its required. Can someone help me with passing parameters properly in GET request?

Comment: have you tried sending data with  json format in body of request

Comment: No. Can you show me how can I do that? @Tejas

Comment: are you familier with postman ?

Comment: Not much. Had used before 2 years.

Comment: Please see this [image](https://ibb.co/jd10Qp) . send your data like this . i've attached postman screenshot .

Comment: But I get the data in browser correctly. I face issue in code. How can I escape the double quotes in the url?

Comment: because you  are sending data in GET request from your android code . send data in POST request with json body

Comment: @Tejas wouldn't that require change in web service? Because with post request and parameters in body, it resolves the error. I get Status code OK in response, but I get no data. And changing Web service is not possible as its being used from ios and web applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`URLEncoder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder) to encode your URL parameter strings.

Encode your `typeInfo` and the `{` preceding it.

Comment: Encoding `typeInfo` alone had not worked. But encoding `{` with it worked. Thanks